# Bubblewrap don't building .aab with supports for Play Billing 5

Tags: trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

After upload .aab to Play Console, received warning which my app is using play billing 4.0.0 and which need update to version 5.0.0 or above.

I try introduce the follow code in file "build.grade":

```
    dependencies {
        def billingVersion = "5.0.0"
        implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billingVersion"
    }
```

After update with Bubblewrap, continuous with same issue!

My twa-manifest.json:

```
{
  "packageId": "br.com.aquialimentacao.www.twa",
  "host": "www.aquialimentacao.com.br",
  "name": "Aqui Alimentação",
  "launcherName": "Aqui Alimentação",
  "display": "standalone",
  "themeColor": "#BC132B",
  "navigationColor": "#000000",
  "navigationColorDark": "#000000",
  "navigationDividerColor": "#000000",
  "navigationDividerColorDark": "#000000",
  "backgroundColor": "#BC132B",
  "enableNotifications": true,
  "startUrl": "/",
  "iconUrl": "https://www.aquialimentacao.com.br/img/app-icons/app-icon-512x512.png",
  "maskableIconUrl": "https://www.aquialimentacao.com.br/img/app-icons/app-icon-512x512-maskable.png",
  "splashScreenFadeOutDuration": 1000,
  "signingKey": {
    "path": "/home/guga/Documentos/Profissional/Projetos/aqui_alimentacao/TWA/1.0.9/android.keystore",
    "alias": "AA"
  },
  "appVersionName": "12",
  "appVersionCode": 12,
  "shortcuts": [],
  "generatorApp": "bubblewrap-cli",
  "webManifestUrl": "https://www.aquialimentacao.com.br/manifest.json",
  "fallbackType": "customtabs",
  "features": {
    "playBilling": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "locationDelegation": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "alphaDependencies": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "enableSiteSettingsShortcut": true,
  "isChromeOSOnly": false,
  "isMetaQuest": false,
  "fullScopeUrl": "https://www.aquialimentacao.com.br/",
  "minSdkVersion": 19,
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "fingerprints": [],
  "additionalTrustedOrigins": [],
  "retainedBundles": [],
  "appVersion": "12"
}
```